# Launch an android activity using an android NFC intent on an Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, nfc

I have an android activity which looks something like this:

```
[Activity, IntentFilter(new[] { "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" },DataMimeType = MainActivity.CXLType, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
public class NFC_Android : Activity
{
   ...
}
```

I just want to start an OnCreate activity when NFC is read but I am not sure if a dependency service is required or how to utilize it if so.

This is a xamarin.forms application so I only need this to work on Android devices but since all intents are android specific, I am not sure how to make android intents to perform actions against a xamarin.forms application.

Comment: You need a broadcast receiver!

Comment: No, you don't need a broadcast receiver. NFC intents are always activity intents. What problem do you have? What data did you store on the tag? What is `MainActivity.CXLType`?

Comment: So, at the moment I am in a state of deep integration where my app keeps crashing for unknown causes. It may be related to another problem but I figured I would inquire on the right way of doing things NFC wise so that I can rule it out. Also, CXLType is a constant string; public const string CXLType = "text/plain". I just pulled code from the inter-web to build it. All I intend to do is read any record or string from it as a proof of concept that the NFC reading works.

Comment: If you register for the MIME type text/plain, you will only receive notifications for those tags that contain a record with that MIME type as their first record.